# What's the best way to save user data that's login from plugin(facebook or google)?

Tags: database, authentication, facebook-login, google-signin

I have my own login form  for my website. In addition I have also added google and facebook login.

My question is should I add those user data that's login from (fb or google) into my own userdata table or create a different one each for google and facebook.

1) If I add to my existing one, the password column would be left blank(as fb do not provide one) and anyone who knows the email will be able to access it easily.

2) And if I make different table then I think it will become little complicated or slower when trying to access a user data from across the different table.

What's the best choice of doing it or any other method that's better than this?

Answer (score 1):

1. Make sure users have to enter a password when they login with Facebook/Google, or make sure regular users do not use a blank password - users without a password can only login with the Facebook/Google API.
2. Don´t create a separate table, it will only get more complicated. Extend the existing one with IDs (from Facebook and Google).

Comment: For users that login from my login form they need to provide one. But for others using plugin I don't one to provide them additional password other than thier own fb or google password.

Comment: users coming from fb/google login do not need a password anyway. but you can still log them in securely, just transfer their access token to the server and do an api call server side to get their user id, for example - at least that´s how it works for facebook, probably similar to google.